# dplyr: pipes inside of summarize after group_by

Tags: r, group-by, pipe, dplyr, summary

I have this data.frame:

```
df_test = structure(list(`MAE %` = c(-0.0647202646339709, -0.126867775585001, 
-1.81159420289855, -1.03092783505155, -2.0375491194877, -0.160783192796913, 
-0.585827216261999, -0.052988554472234, -0.703351261894911, -0.902996305924203, 
-0.767676767676768, -0.0101091791346543, -0.0134480903711673, 
-0.229357798165138, -0.176407935028625, -0.627062706270627, -1.75706139769261, 
-1.23024009524439, -0.257391763463569, -0.878347259688137, -0.123613523987705, 
-1.65711947626841, -2.11718534838887, -0.256285931980328, -1.87152777777778, 
-0.0552333609500138, -0.943983402489627, -0.541095890410959, 
-0.118607409474639, -0.840453845076341), Profit = c(7260, 2160, 
-7080, 3600, -8700, 6300, -540, 10680, -1880, -3560, -720, 5400, 
5280, 1800, 11040, -240, -2320, 2520, 10300, -2520, 8400, -9240, 
-5190, 7350, -6790, 3600, -3240, 8640, 7150, -2400)), .Names = c("MAE %", 
"Profit"), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now i want some summary statistics like:

```
df_test %>% 
    group_by(win.g = Profit > 0) %>%
    summarise(GroupCnt  = n(),
              TopMAE    = filter(`MAE %` > -1) %>% sum(Profit),
              BottomMAE = filter(`MAE %` <= -1) %>% sum(Profit))
```

So we group data if Profit > 0 or <= 0. Then i want sum() of Profit for rows with MAE % <= -1 and for MAE % > -1. Grouping must be used for TopMAE, BottomMAE calculation.

Expected result is like:

```
#  win.g CroupCnt TopMAE BottomMAE
#1 FALSE       14 -15100    -39320
#2  TRUE       16  95360      6120
```

But my R code does not working. I have an error:

> Error: no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "logical"

I have changed my code according to error:

```
df_test %>% 
    group_by(win.g = Profit > 0) %>%
    summarise(UnderStop = n(),
              TopMAE    = filter(., `MAE %` > -1) %>% sum(Profit),
              BottomMAE = filter(., `MAE %` <= -1) %>% sum(Profit))
```

But the result is none. I have an error again:

> Error: incorrect length (14), expecting: 16

I tried to understand grouping behavior and how to use piping inside summarise after grouping, but i did not success. Spend whole day on it.

HOW can i get my expected result table? Please help me to understand dplyr logic when grouping and calculating some functions on  that groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? (Only asking because I get different results thatn your output),

```
df_test %>% 
       group_by(win.g = Profit > 0) %>% 
       summarise(CroupCnt = n(), TopMAE = sum(Profit[`MAE %` > -1]), 
                                 BottomMAE = sum(Profit[`MAE %` <= -1]))

#Source: local data frame [2 x 4]

#  win.g CroupCnt TopMAE BottomMAE
#  (lgl)    (int)  (dbl)     (dbl)
#1 FALSE       14 -15100    -39320
#2  TRUE       16  95360      6120
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It is really readable and fast. My expected numbers were wrong as I see now. Have corrected that in my post. @Benjamin gives us very good solution too, and more dplyr styled. I voted for yours as you were the first one.
But what about piping inside summarize and mutate and so on? Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I prefer to work a problem like this with the recognition that you are performing your grouped operations on two dimensions, but your code only uses one dimension.  Here's an example performing the same work over two dimensions.  It's a bit more code than @Sotos provided, but provides the same result he got.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_test %>%
  #* Group on two dimensions
  group_by(win.g = Profit > 0,
           top = ifelse(`MAE %` > -1, "TopMAE", "BottomMAE")) %>%
  summarise(GroupCnt = n(),
            SumProfit = sum(Profit)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%

  #* Collapse the GroupCnt
  group_by(win.g) %>%
  mutate(GroupCnt = sum(GroupCnt)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%

  #* From long to wide
  spread(top, SumProfit)
```

Comment: Wasn't sure about the results as they are different than OP's expected results but If you got the same ones then I guess its true

Comment: I was a little concerned too until I saw your answer.  And for what it's worth, I've found that your answer is about twice as fast as mine on this example.  When I expanded it to 1000 rows, it was four times faster. (2 vs 4 milliseconds).  If I were to be using really large data sets, I'd probably convert over to your answer.

Comment: Thank you too! Very good dplyr styled example. You have showed me new way in dplyr using.  I guess we can omit  two ungroup() and one group_by() while summarize peel of one grouping level :). It will be a little less code and faster.
But what about piping inside summarize and mutate and so on? Is it possible or not?